# Loading content script only in sub directory of a site

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How do I load `Chrome` content script on only sub-directory of a site. For example:

**In:** `https://www.example.com/#!/video/*` 
**Not in:** `https://www.example.com/`

So I do not want to load on the home page but rather in the video directory. I have tried match pattern like this but it does not work.

`"matches":  ["*://*.example.com/*", "*://*.example.com/#!/video/*"]`

My urls look like this: `www.example.com/#!/video/random_numbers/some-random-string`

**PS:** I also want to load the script again after every ajax requests from the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that URL-fragments (URL hashes) aren't supported in `"matches"` and there's no way to use `"content_scripts"` section to autoinject/autoremove scripts based on hash change because the page isn't actually reloaded.

Remove the entire `"content_scripts"` section from manifest.json and use  [webNavigation API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) to inject/activate the content script only when needed (requires `"permissions: ["webNavigation"]`).

- background.js:

  ```
  chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(function(details) {
      injectOrActivate("onCommitted", details);
  });
  chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(function(details) {
      injectOrActivate("onHashChange", details);
  });

  function injectOrActivate(event, details) {
      var tabId = details.tabId;

      if (details.url.indexOf("#") < 0) {
          deactivateContentScript(tabId);
          return;
      }

      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {code: "injectedStatus"}, function(res) {
          if (res[0] != "injected") {
              chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "content.js"}, function(res) {
                 activateContentScript(tabId);
              });
          } else {
              activateContentScript(tabId);
          }
      }
  }

  function activateContentScript(tabId) {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {action: "activate"});
  }

  function deactivateContentScript(tabId) {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {action: "deactivate"});
  }
  ```
- content.js:

  ```
  var injectedStatus = "injected";
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
      switch (msg.action) {
          case "activate":
              doSomething();
              break;
          case "deactivate":
              stopDoingSomething();
              break;
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: Removing ```"*://*.example.com/*"``` does not help either.

Comment: another way is regular content scripts and only do stuff based on the current url by watching it change. also, the part about handling later page changes through ajax is already covered in s.o.

Comment: @ZigMandel, if there's a duplicate answer I've missed, flag the question accordingly and I'll remove my answer.

Comment: just the 2nd part is duplicate: "PS: I also want to load the script again after every ajax requests from the page."